# Recovering from a problem in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I edited a config file in Ubuntu and made it unbootable. In order to fix it, I booted the install CD and meant to revert the changes.

The problem is, it wont let me save the changes to the file. The file is owned by root -- I've no idea how to edit it while I'm booted from the CD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running from the command line

"***sudo gedit /pathtoyourfile***"

That should open gedit, a text editor with GUI, with sudo privileges

Comment: how do I access something on the hard drive from terminal once I've booted to cd?

Comment: Okay - have it now. I just typed "sudo gedit" (no file) once I booted from CD and then navigated within the GUI program to the file on the hard drive. Thank you.

Comment: You welcome. I love it when me answer works. Yeah!